# Update SQL record based on a record in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to run a query, that compares two tables. I got a table called mw_email_blacklist, this table is holding about 200k records of my blacklisted emails. In my other table, I got my list subscribers, they got a 'status' field, which can equal "Blacklisted" and then they can't receive an email.

Both tables got a 'email' field, so my plan was to do a where clause based on the email field. This however is not really working out. Can somebody maybe help me?

Included SQL:

```
UPDATE
    `mw_list_subscriber` mls,
    `mw_email_blacklist` meb
SET
    mls.`status` = "Blacklisted";
WHERE
    mls.`email` = meb.`email`;
```

This SQL actually counted something that could be the right amount of emails that should be blacklisted, but I couldn't get it to work when writing it to an update clause.

```
SELECT  count(ls.email) 
FROM mw_list_subscriber ls
WHERE EXISTS (
    select email from mw_email_blacklist eb
    WHERE ls.email = eb.email
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your intention correctly, a general approach could be:

`UPDATE mw_list_subscriber mls , mw_email_blacklist AS meb
SET mls.status='Blacklisted' 
WHERE mls.email = meb.email`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM mw_email_blacklist AS mls 
INNER JOIN mw_email_blacklist AS meb 
ON mls.ema' at line 3

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my answer for a MySQL code that should work with your table structure.

Comment: Working! Thanks :)